# Django view to call api

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So i'm using django view to call api post method but its giving me 400 error

As i encounter csrf forbidden error b4, im using the `@csrf_exempt` for now.
I tried doing post method on both the API itself and also using the view to call the api.

However when using the view to call, i got 400 error when both are using the same post value to post.

Posting using api:
QueryDict: {'book': ['Second '], 'author': ['Ban'], 'date': ['2018-01-10 08:00AM']}
[22/Jan/2018 18:56:09] "POST /api/test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 61

Posting using view:
QueryDict: {}
[22/Jan/2018 18:56:12] "POST /api/test/?book=Second+&author=Ban&date=2018-01-10+08%3A00AM HTTP/1.1" 400 36
[22/Jan/2018 18:56:12] "POST /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 19

Here is my code

**models.py**

```
class TestPost(models.Model):
    book = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class TestPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p")

    class Meta:
        model = TestPost
        fields = ('id', 'book', 'author', 'date')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import requests

def my_django_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test/', params=request.POST)
    else:
        r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test/', params=request.GET)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return HttpResponse('Yay, it worked')
    return HttpResponse('Could not save data')

class TestPostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = TestPost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestPostSerializer
```

Comment: Why are you getting your Django app to POST to itself? That's unnecessary. Just call the relevant code directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the API you're calling, but I think you might need to send `data` in post request and not `params`.

```
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test/', data=request.POST)
```

Comment: Sorry, what about when I wanted to display the json data that i GET/POST from the APi ? i use `return request.GET` and `return Response({'Message': 'You have successfully register'}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED})` but both cant seems to work

Comment: `r.data` might return the api response.

Comment: i tried both     `if r.status_code == 200:
        return HttpResponse(r.data)` and     `if r.status_code == 200:
        return r.data` and both gave this error `'Response' object has no attribute 'data'`

Comment: My bad. Depending on the response type of the api, you can use `r.text`, `r.content` and `r.json()`. You can consult the documentation - http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

Comment: Ah this will help me alot. Thanks